# $varName not found in NetBeans but varName gets found

Tags: search, netbeans, netbeans-7, file-search

I'm having a bit of an idiot problem with NetBeans since some time.

i open a file which has a variable named `$dayFrom` i select the variable and press
ctrl + F and fet the search box shown.

Now here comes the idiot part... it does not find the variable! even the one I selected...
I tried so in both NB 7.1 and 7.3 and it is still present in both of them. 
I imported the settings from 7.1 to 7.3 so I am guesing some option is messed up there.

Anyone has an idea where to turn the damn thing on?

And one more funny thing when i search `dayFrom` withot the `$` sign it works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

This was the error.... from my side.... regular expresion was turned on... this shuold be HIGHLIGHTED in any way... it drove me crazy for like 2 days...

[image]